# PrimeFaces Rio layout+theme color customisation and good practices

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, themes

We're starting a website project and came accross the paid [Rio theme](http://www.primefaces.org/layouts/rio).
What we're wondering is how far can we go in customisation without having to touch the theme's CSS, and if buying the layout and theme is worth in our case at all.

Rio is not specifically the only option we want, we just want to be able to do the following:
We'd like to change the look of the website depending on the logged in user.

Theme customisation:

- The `.ui-panel-titlebar` ("Downloads" example in [Rio's Dashboard page](http://www.primefaces.org/rio/dashboard.xhtml)) seem
  to be hardcoded to be purple `#5C6BC0`. Is there any chance to change
  that background by adding or changing a `class`? The important part is
  that we don't change the core CSS files of the theme and preferably
  don't create additional CSS classes nor make use of precompiling
  frameworks.
- Can we edit the logo on top left only to make the menu move slightly to the bottom? I tried with a bigger image through Chrome's
  DevTools but the image overlays to the bottom.
- Is is a good practice to think this way: We're thinking to have a WebpageThemeController with methods that would return the correct
  class strings depending on the user, to put in the different parts of
  the website.
- Is considering Primefaces' layout+themes good in this case? If not, how should we proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Next version of RİO will have less integration to easily customize colors, fonts ...

You can even use multiple layouts per user by the way, here is a tutorial;

https://youtu.be/jbNdtndIsqk